# What is the difference between cout, cerr, clog of iostream header in c++? When to use which one?

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, clog

I tried researching the difference between `cout`, `cerr` and `clog` on the internet but couldn't find a perfect answer. I still am not clear on when to use which. Can anyone explain to me, through simple programs and illustrate a perfect situation on when to use which one?

I visited [this site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_input_output.htm) which shows a small program on `cerr` and `clog`, but the output obtained over there can also be obtained using `cout`. So, I'm confused over each one's exact use.

Comment: Each one has a computer-recognized stream, `stdout`, `stdin` (for `cin`), and `stderr` that it uses by default. I believe `clog` is just `cerr` with a buffering change.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`stdout` and `stderr` are different streams, even though they both refer to console output by default. Redirecting (piping) one of them (e.g. `program.exe >out.txt`) would not affect the other.

Generally, `stdout` should be used for actual program output, while all information and error messages should be printed to `stderr`, so that if the user redirects output to a file, information messages are still printed on the screen and not to the output file.

Answer (score 158):

Generally you use `std::cout` for normal output, `std::cerr` for errors, and `std::clog` for "logging" (which can mean whatever you want it to mean).

The major difference is that `std::cerr` is not buffered like the other two.

---

In relation to the old C `stdout` and `stderr`, `std::cout` corresponds to `stdout`, while `std::cerr` and `std::clog` both corresponds to `stderr` (except that `std::clog` is buffered).

Comment: I've read that `clog` also outputs to `cerr`. So based on that, which one do you choose? If `clog` is normally for "logging", why would I want that to go to the error stream? Logs seem more like "normal logs" (a.k.a. `cout`) than errors.

Comment: @void.pointer As I said in my answer, both `cerr` and `clog` uses the standard "error" output, but `clog` is buffered which might be why it seems more like `cout`. Which one to pick for error output? Depends I guess, on more reasons than I can list and it has to be decided from case to case.

Comment: what do you mean by "buffered"?

Comment: @simplename Output isn't written directly, it's stored in a *buffer* until the buffer is *flushed*. Output to a file or terminal is historically slow (terminals or consoles are still slow), writing character by character is ineffective, writing a chunk of bytes is much more effective.

Comment: context: cerr is not buffered because if the program were to crash in a non-graceful way, you might have useful debugging info stuck in a buffer, rather than having been printed to stderr.

Answer (score 28):

**Standard output stream (cout):** 
 `cout` is the instance of the `ostream` class. `cout` is used to produce output on the standard output device which is usually the display screen. The data needed to be displayed on the screen is inserted in the standard output stream (`cout`) using the insertion operator (`<<`).

**Un-buffered standard error stream (cerr):** `cerr` is the standard error stream which is used to output the errors. This is also an instance of the `ostream` class. As `cerr` is **un-buffered** so it is used when we need to display the error message immediately. It does not have any buffer to store the error message and display later.

**Buffered standard error stream (clog):** This is also an instance of `ostream` class and used to display errors but unlike `cerr` the error is first inserted into a **buffer** and is stored in the buffer until it is not fully filled.

further reading : [basic-input-output-c](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-input-output-c/)

Comment: `until it is not fully filled.`--shouldn't this say `until it IS fully filled`?

Comment: FYI: It looks like [TutorialsPoint.com has directly plagiarized your answer, here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-cerr-and-clog-streams-in-cplusplus). I emailed TutorialsPoint on 23 Oct. 2020 about possible plagiarism, and they replied, "Sure Gabriel, we will look into it.", on 25 Oct. 2020. I never heard back from them after that, but it appears they did not look into it.

Comment: The plagiarism on TutorialsPoint.com is still there. What's the legal situation about this?

Answer (score 12):

- Use **cout** for the standard output.
- Use **cerr** to show errors.
- Use **clog** for logging.

Comment: Wrong, cerr is slower than cout because of non-buffer! Just like write vs printf

Answer (score 12):

The difference of these 3 streams is buffering.

1. With cerr, the output flushs

   - immediately (because cerr does not use buffer).
2. With clog, the output flushs

   - after you finish your current function.
   - explicitly call the function flush.
3. With cout, the output flushs

   - after you have call to any output streams (cout, cerr, clog).
   - after you finish your current function.
   - explicitly call the function flush.

Please check the following code, and run DEBUG through 3 lines: f(std::clog), f(std::cerr), f(std::out), then open 3 output files to see what happened. You can swap these 3 lines to see what will happen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void f(std::ostream &os)
{
    std::cin.clear(); // clear EOF flags
    std::cin.seekg(0, std::cin.beg); // seek to begin

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))   //input from the file in.txt
        os << line << "\n";   //output to the file out.txt
}

void test()
{
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    std::ofstream out("out.txt"), err("err.txt"), log("log.txt");
    std::streambuf *cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf(), *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(), *cerrbuf = std::cerr.rdbuf(),
                    *clogbuf = std::clog.rdbuf();

    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cin to in.txt!
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt!
    std::cerr.rdbuf(err.rdbuf());
    std::clog.rdbuf(log.rdbuf());


    f(std::clog);
    f(std::cerr);
    f(std::cout);

    std::cin.rdbuf(cinbuf);
    std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(cerrbuf);
    std::clog.rdbuf(clogbuf);
}

int main()
{
    test();
    std::cout << "123";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From a draft C++17 standard document:

> 30.4.3  Narrow stream objects  [narrow.stream.objects]
>
> `istream cin;`
>
> 1 The object `cin` controls input from a stream buffer associated with the object `stdin`, declared in `<cstdio>` (30.11.1).
>
> 2 After the object `cin` is initialized, `cin.tie()` returns `&cout`. Its state is otherwise the same as required for `basic_ios<char>::init` (30.5.5.2).
>
> `ostream cout;`
>
> 3 The object `cout` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stdout`, declared in `<cstdio>` (30.11.1).
>
> `ostream cerr;`
>
> 4 The object `cerr` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stderr`, declared in`<cstdio>` (30.11.1).
>
> 5 After the object `cerr` is initialized, `cerr.flags() & unitbuf` is nonzero and `cerr.tie()` returns `&cout`. Its state is otherwise the same as required for `basic_ios<char>::init` (30.5.5.2).
>
> `ostream clog;`
>
> 6 The object `clog` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stderr`, declared in `<cstdio>` (30.11.1).

### Discussion...

**`cout` writes to `stdout`; `cerr` and `clog` to `stderr`**

Standard Out (`stdout`) is intended to receive non-error, non-diagnostic output from the program, such as output from successful processing that can be displayed to the end-user or streamed into some further processing stage.

Standard Error (`stderr`) is intended for diagnostic output, such as warning and error messages that indicate the program hasn't or may not have produced the output the user might expect.  This may be displayed to the end user even if the output data is piped to a further processing stage, or it could be redirected to a log file, for example.

**`cin` and `cerr` are tied to `cout`**

They both flush `cout` before handling I/O operations themselves.  This ensures prompts sent to `cout` are visible before the program blocks to read input from `cin`, and that earlier output to `cout` is flushed before writing an error through `cerr`, which keeps the messages in chronological order of their generation when both are directed to the same terminal/file/etc..

This contrasts with `clog` - if you write there it won't be buffered and isn't tied to anything, so it will buffer decent sized amounts of logging before flushing.  This yields the highest throughput of messages, but means the messages may not be quickly visible to a would-be consumer reading the terminal or tailing the log, even if an error was written through `cerr` and is on-screen or in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Both **cout** and **clog** are buffered but **cerr** is un-buffered and all of these are predefined objects which are instances of class ostream.
The basic use of these three are **cout** is used for standard output whereas **clog** and **cerr** is used for showing errors.
The main point why **cerr** is un-buffered is may be because suppose you have several outputs in the buffer and an error exception is mentioned in the code then you need to display that error immediately which can be done by **cerr** effectively.

Please correct me if I am wrong.