# Send output to systemd-journal from C++ program

Tags: c++11, journal

I have some Python programs that I'd like to convert to C++11 code as a way of learning the language. The target platform is Debian, kernel version >=4.2 (i.e. systemd).

In Python I can log debugging/logging information to the system log using the [`syslog` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html).
In C I would be able to `#include <syslog.h>`. But, from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944427/how-do-i-create-a-log-entry-for-the-systemd-journal) I understand that for the current C++ implementation there is no such implementation (anymore). If the program is a service (or daemon?) this would apparently happen automagically although I don't gather how the message priority would be distinguished.

I've Googled around but can't really find a solution to my problem: **How do I send information to the system log from within a C++11 program?**

EDIT: (throws hands in the air and gives up ;-) ) Since there doesn't seem to be a native solution to my problem and I'm still in the starting phase of learning C++, I now consider to use **C** i.s.o. C++ since C natively supports syslog with `syslog.h`.

Comment: This looks like you were looking for a reason to not learn C++ and learn C instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also send log data to journald via the `sd_journal_send(3)` or `sd_journal_print(3)` c-functions.

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html gives more info and examples on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SysLogAppender](https://github.com/wilx/log4cplus/blob/master/include/log4cplus/syslogappender.h) of [Log4Cplus](https://github.com/wilx/log4cplus/). But the question and therefore the answer are opinion-based etc etc