# C++ program will not start when trying to redirect console output to text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a C++ program and redirect the console output to a text file. From my understanding, this is achieved by:

`./program > console.txt`

I am able to compile and run the program using `./program` fine and get the console output I am expecting. When I run  `./program > console.txt` nothing happens, I simply enter a linebreak and am on a new line in my console input (looks like the following)

```
$ ./program > console.txt
```

I have also tried append instead of redirect using `./program >> console.txt`, as well as `./program | tee console.txt`.

I know I can alter the C++ program to write to a file using <fstream> but I'd like to figure out why the redirect is not starting the program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps your program is writing to stderr, not stdout? Does  ```./program 2> console.txt``` work?

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" perhaps the program is waiting for *input*? You only redirect the standard output, you still need to provide input if your program reads from standard input.

Comment: @user2233706 That worked perfectly it's running as expected now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The mischievous `std::cerr` strikes again...

Comment: See [What is the difference between cout, cerr, clog of iostream header in c++? When to use which one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772842/what-is-the-difference-between-cout-cerr-clog-of-iostream-header-in-c-when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting to stderr, do `./program 2> console.txt`. `2` is the file descriptor number for stderr.

stderr should only be used for error output.